# Android: use unicode characters in option menu

Tags: android, unicode, toast, optionmenu

I want to know how can I use unicode chars like arabic or persian in option menu?
I acctually use this class to reshape string value and set those value as text of my objects like button, text view and ...
but I dont know how can I set those value as option menu text

way that I reshape char:

```
public void setface() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/"+fonts+"");

    TextView shoma = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shoma);
    shoma.setTypeface(face);
    String shoma_txt = shoma.getText().toString();
    shoma.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(shoma_txt));
}
```

**face** is a function in reshaper.java (because it's too long I could not post it here)

now how can I use this method to set option menu tittle (or Toast text)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question. Do you want to change the font type face? To achieve this in a Toast Notification you can create a Custom Toast View. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#CustomToastView